# Unable to use route for testing controller in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a complete newbie to RoR. I am writing rspec for an application. My route file consists of:

```
        devise_for :sub_users, controllers: {
          sessions: 'sub_users/sessions',
          passwords: 'sub_users/passwords',
          registrations: 'sub_users/registrations',
          invitations: 'sub_users/invitations'
        }

        devise_scope :sub_user do
          get '/sub_users/invitation/request/new', to: "sub_users/invitations#new_invitation_request", as: 'new_sub_user_invitation_request'
          post '/sub_users/invitation/request/create', to: "sub_users/invitations#create_invitation_request", as: 'create_sub_user_invitation_request'
        end
```

I am writing rspec as below:

```
      describe 'GET #new_invitation_request' do
            subject { post :new_invitation_request, params: params }
            let(:params) { { email: 'test@gmail.com'} }

            let(:user) { build_stubbed(:user) }

            before(:each) do
              sign_in(user)
            end

            it 'should test condition here' do
            subject
            end
            end
```

But it gives me this error on subejct. I have searched every similar question but none seems to resolve my issue. Any help would be appreciated:

```
   AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/sub_users/invitation/request/new".
   This may happen for two reasons:
 
   1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:
 
     devise_scope :user do
       get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
     end
 
   2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
      If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:
 
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Comment: shouldn't the `subject` be `subject { post :new_invitation_request_path, params: params }` instead of `subject { post :new_invitation_request, params: params }`? try and see if this works.

Comment: Nopes, on adding path to it, it now gives this error 
```ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>":new_invitation_request_path", :controller=>"sub_users/invitations", :email=>"test@gmail.com"}```

Comment: @SachinSingh nope. In a controller test you're actually calling the method directly on the controller. It doesn't actually go through the routes and the test merely checks that there is a route that vaguely resembles the parameters. The fact that this test doesn't tell you that the route is missing since `post` is being used instead of `get` is one of the reasons you should'nt be using them.

Comment: @SachinSingh The routes here are also very unconventional but thats kind of a side note.

Answer (score 1):

### Do not use controller specs

They are just a thin wrapper around `ActionDispatch::ControllerTest` which was completely replaced by `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` way back in 2016. `ActionDispatch::ControllerTest` (and controller specs which wrap it) still exists in the Rails codebase simply for legacy compatibility but its use is discouraged.

This depreachiated approach stubs out huge portions of the framework (like the routes) by creating an instance of the controller with a faked Rack request. The request doesn't actually pass through the middleware - in the case of Devise this is a fatal flaw since Warden which actually does the heavy lifting in authenticating users is Rack middleware.

Thus the controller blows up since the Devise mapping hasn't been insterted when the request goes through the router middleware (thats what `devise_for` does). You can "fix" the problem by including the deprechiated [controller testing helpers](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise/Devise/Test/ControllerHelpers) which completly mocks out the actual authententication system - but what are you actually testing at that point?

### Write request specs

Request specs look somewhat similiar but send actual HTTP request that pass through your entire Rails app. They are just as fast (if not faster) in modern versions of Rails.

```
# spec/requests/subuser_invitations_spec.rb
RSpec.describe('Subuser Invitations', type: :request) do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before(:each) do
    login_as(user)
  end

  describe "GET /sub_users/invitations/new" do
    subject { get '/sub_users/invitation/request/new' }
    it { should be_successful }
  end

  describe "POST /sub_users/invitations" do
    subject { post '/sub_users/invitations', params: { ... } }
    it "creates an invitation" do
       # just an example...
       expect do
         post '/sub_users/invitations', params: { ... }
       end.to change(Invitation, :count).by(1)
       expect(response).to have_http_status :created
    end

    it "emails the invitation to the user" do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

The key difference really is that controller specs desribe methods on your controller while a good request spec really describes the endpoints that your application exposes to HTTP.

It should also be noted that [in the Rails conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) you never put `show`, `index`, `create`, `delete` or `update` in the path.

Thats because the HTTP verbs POST, PATCH and DELETE are used to destinguish the intent. Look at the routes generated by the Devise invitable gem if you want an example of what you actually should be doing.

`new` and `edit` are exceptions to that rule but its because they simply exist to display a form.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried the above method but still get route exception. 
`ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches`  though the route exists

Comment: In your question you're mixing up POST and GET. Have you addressed that problem?